# Animating a flashing bell in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am having problems with making a simple systemIcon flash in SwiftUI.
I got the animation working, but it has a silly behaviour if the layout of
a LazyGridView changes or adapts. Below is a video of its erroneous behaviour.
The flashing bell stays in place but when the layout rearranges the bell
starts transitioning in from the bottom of the parent view thats not there anymore.

Has someone got a suggestion how to get around this?

Here is a working example which is similar to my problem

```
import SwiftUI

struct FlashingBellLazyVGrid: View {
    @State var isAnimating = false
    @State var showChart = true
    
    var body: some View {
        
        let columns = [GridItem(.adaptive(minimum: 300), spacing: 50, alignment: .center)]
        
        
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                showChart.toggle()
            }) {
                VStack {
                    Circle()
                        .fill(showChart ? Color.green : Color.red)
                        .shadow(color: Color.gray, radius: 5, x: 2, y: 2)
                    Text("Charts")
                        .foregroundColor(Color.primary)
                    
                }.frame(width: 150, height: 50)
            }
            
            ScrollView {
                LazyVGrid (
                    columns: columns, spacing: 50
                    ) {
                    
                   
                    ForEach(0 ..< 25) { item in
                        ZStack {
                            Rectangle()
                                .fill(Color.red)
                                .cornerRadius(15)
                            
                            VStack {
                                HStack {
                                    Text(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/"Hello, World!"/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                                    Spacer()
                                    Image(systemName: "bell.fill")
                                        .foregroundColor(Color.yellow)
                                        .opacity(self.isAnimating ? 1 : 0)
                                        .animation(Animation.easeInOut(duration: 0.66).repeatForever(autoreverses: false))
                                        .onAppear{ self.isAnimating = true }
                                }.padding(50)
                                if showChart {
                                Rectangle()
                                    .fill(Color.green)
                                    .frame(height: 200)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                   
                                                       
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
}

struct FlashingBellLazyVGrid_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        FlashingBellLazyVGrid()
    }
}
```

how it looks like before you click the showChart button at the top

[image: initial state]

[image: initial state blinking]

After you toggle the button it looks like the bells are erroneously moving into place from the bottom of the screen. and toggling it back to its original state doesn't resolve this bug subsequently.

[[image: bells moving into view from bottom of view 2]

[image: bells moving erratically]

Comment: Might be good to include a [mre] since that behavior isn't replicated by just the code you've included.

Comment: Thanks will send tomorrow. How would you make a systemIcon flash in place. Animation seems to always transition from some edge somewhere. how do you just make it flash in place ignoring the bounding parent view in the first place?

Comment: @jnpdx take a look at this example above now. its doing the weird thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the animation is basing itself off of the original size of the view. In order to trick it into recognizing the new view size, I used `.id(UUID())` on the outside of the grid. In a real world application, you'd probably want to be careful to store this ID somewhere and only refresh it when needed -- not on every re-render like I'm doing:

```
struct FlashingBellLazyVGrid: View {
    @State var showChart = true
    
    let columns = [GridItem(.adaptive(minimum: 300), spacing: 50, alignment: .center)]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                showChart.toggle()
            }) {
                VStack {
                    Circle()
                        .fill(showChart ? Color.green : Color.red)
                        .shadow(color: Color.gray, radius: 5, x: 2, y: 2)
                    Text("Charts")
                        .foregroundColor(Color.primary)
                    
                }.frame(width: 150, height: 50)
            }
            
            ScrollView {
                LazyVGrid (
                    columns: columns, spacing: 50
                ) {
                    ForEach(0 ..< 25) { item in
                        ZStack {
                            Rectangle()
                                .fill(Color.red)
                                .cornerRadius(15)
                            
                            VStack {
                                SeparateComponent()
                                if showChart {
                                    Rectangle()
                                        .fill(Color.green)
                                        .frame(height: 200)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                .id(UUID()) //<-- Here
            }
        }
        
    }
}

struct SeparateComponent : View {
    @State var isAnimating : Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text("Hello, World!")
            Spacer()
            Image(systemName: "bell.fill")
                .foregroundColor(Color.yellow)
                .opacity(self.isAnimating ? 1 : 0)
                .animation(Animation.easeInOut(duration: 0.66).repeatForever(autoreverses: false))
                .onAppear{
                    self.isAnimating = true
                }
        }
        .padding(50)
    }
}
```

I also separated out the blinking component into its own view, since there were already problematic things happening with the existing logic with `onAppear`, which wouldn't affect newly-scrolled-to items correctly. This may need refactoring for your particular case as well, but this should get you started.

Comment: weird that flashing an icon seems broken in more complicated views in SwiftUI. As soon as you have changing parent frames it messes up. its ok if you have a fixed frame.